# Can someone show this problem for this example step by step

Tags: phasor

Plot the magnitude and phase of the following complex functions:

G(w) = 1/(1+jw)

We never went over this in lecture but apparently I have homework on it. Looks pretty simple but just don't know where to begin. Could anyone maybe walk through the process of it rather than just answer?

**edit: I apologize for my ambiguity here is the problem word for word:**

Plot the magnitude and phase of the following complex functions:

(i)   G(w) = 1/(1+jw)

(ii)  G(ω) = −1/(1+jω)

(iii) G(ω) = j/(1+jω)

Comment: Just to check where you're at, do you know how to find the magnitude and phase of the given function? Or are you just not sure how to plot them?

Comment: You are using plural "*Plot the magnitude and phase of the **following** complex function**s***", and you are only presenting one function. Did you forget to add other functions?

Comment: Have you covered argument and modulus of complex numbers in classes?

Comment: @jramsay42 I have no idea where to begin we never went over this concept in lecture yet.

Comment: @HarrySvensson just edited my quesition I apologize!

Comment: @Chu no we have not gone over argument and modulus of complex number in class

Comment: It’s time to do some independent learning, then.

Comment: @JasonKim Your 1st function is just a single pole low pass RC filter in standard 1 radian per second analysis format with R=1 and C=1 and therefore \$\tau=1\$.  Once you've analyzed things in this form, converting it into any particular RC low pass filter just involves two steps: one to set the desired impedance and another to set the frequency. You'll get familiar with the ideas soon, I'm sure.

Answer (score 3):

> Plot the magnitude and phase of the following complex functions:
>
> G(w) = 1/(1+jw)

The \$j\$ is the same as \$i\$, the \$i\$ (imaginary) axis is perpendicular to the real axis. This means that we can use the Pythagorean theorem if we want to calculate the magnitude of a complex number.

So the magnitude of \$a+ib\$  is \$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\$, and this is also the absolute value of any function. Just add some straight lines to denote absolute value, like this: \$|a+ib|\$.

So the \$|G(w)|\$ is \$|\frac{1}{1+jw}|=\frac{|1|}{|1+jw|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+w^2}}\$. Now all you need to do is to insert real numbers into the *w* variable.

---

As mentioned before, the \$i\$ axis is perpendicular to the real axis. This means that we can retrieve our phase, \$\phi,=\tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})=\arctan(\frac{b}{a})\$.

The phase of two multiplied complex number is the same as adding their individual phases. \$i\$ is an example of this, \$i^2=-1 => 90+90=180\$. And the phase of two divided complex numbers is simply subtracting the phase of the denominator from the phase of the numerator.

So the \$\phi\$  of, say \$\frac{3+4i}{1+2i}\$ for an example is \$\phi=\arctan(\frac{4}{3})-\arctan(\frac{2}{1})\$.

The phase, \$\phi\$, is sometimes called the angle of a complex value, which is sometimes called argument, arg{}.

The \$\arg\{G(w)\}\$ is \$\arg\{\frac{1}{1+jw}\}=\arctan(\frac{0}{1})-\arctan(\frac{w}{1})=-\arctan(w)\$

Don't forget to multiply the \$\arg\{\}\$ with \$\frac{180}{\pi}\$ if you want it in regular degrees.

---

The *w* in your function is a frequency in radians per second which can be translated to regular Hertz by simply multiplying by \$2\pi\$. You can try 0 Hz, 0.1 Hz, 1 Hz, 10 Hz, 100 Hz. The actual values I recommend you to replace *w* with are 0, 0.628, 6.28, 62.8 and 628.

Those points will probably give you enough data to extrapolate the rest of the function.