# Why can't we add resistance and reactance directly to form impedance?

Tags: ac, impedance

Why we cannot add resistance and reactance directly to form impedance. Why should we use pythagoras theorem formula in order to calculate impedance ?

Comment: My answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/363779/can-someone-show-this-problem-for-this-example-step-by-step/363787#363787) is very related to this question.

Comment: You *do* just add them.  However, they are vector quantities, so need to be added that way, not as scalars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in complex algebra,  magnitude of a complex quantity \$ a + jb \$ is not equal to \$ a + b \$ . But \$ \sqrt {a^2 + b ^2}  \$.

The resistance is a real quantity. While reactance is an imaginary quantity.

Resistance = \$ R \$

Inductive reactance = \$jX_L\$

Capacitive reactance = \$ -jX_C\$

The sum of them will be impedance, \$ Z = R + j(X_L - X_C)\$ , which is a complex quantity.

Why Resistance is a real quantity and Reactance is an imaginary quantity ? The Answer is in their respective phasor diagrams between Voltage and current.

For eg. in series RLC circuit:

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

[Impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance) is a complex quantity whose real part is resistance and imaginary part is reactance. So to get the magnitude of impedance you have to use 'pythagoras theorem'.